# Jump to next div and have it centred on screen when user scrolls

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm building a one page site, and wanting to have multiple divs, that are approximatly `400px` (but vary) on top of each other. Instead of a smooth scroll, I would like jump to the next div and have it centred on the screen, at the same time adjust the opacity of the content above and below to draw attention to the centre div.

I have tried playing with a few scrolling plugins but have not had anything do what I'm after, most of them are geared towards a full page div, not one only a 1/3 or so the height of the page.

Can someone point me towards something I can adapt to perform this.

Comment: You have to regard what you have tried in your question. i.e code example.

Comment: not using wordpress.. I have tried varius items in Scroll Magic, and other Js fiddle solutions posted on here for other requests

Answer (score 0):

1. Add an event listener to the document which looks for elements with the class `.next`
2. Get the distance from the top of the viewport to the top of the element in question
3. subtract half the value of the viewport height minus the height of the element.
4. If the element is bigger than the viewport, scoll to to top of the element
5. Or scroll the element into the middle.
6. Set the opacity of the unfocused elements.

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/28acoh94/1/))

```
(function(){
    "use strict";
    document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        if(e.target.className.indexOf('next') >= 0) {
            var current = e.target.parentElement
            var next = current.nextElementSibling || false;
            if(next) {
                var nextNext = next.nextElementSibling;

                var height = next.offsetHeight;
                var top = next.offsetTop;
                var viewHeight = window.innerHeight;
                if(viewHeight - height > 0) {
                    var scrollTo = top - ((viewHeight - height) / 2);
                } else {
                    var scrollTo = top;
                }
                window.scroll(0, scrollTo);

                current.style.opacity = '0.5';
                next.style.opacity = '1';
                if(nextNext) nextNext.style.opacity = '0.5';
            }
        }
    }, false);
})();
```